# Soldiers linger around for ages before a level finishes

Tags: toy-soldiers

In the Steam version of the original Toy Soldiers game, whenever I finish a level, a few ordinary soldiers will stick around for sometimes as much as ten minutes before the level actually finishes. This has happened with every level in the game that has soldiers anywhere near the end. It really harms the experience since I've been spending as long waiting for the level to actually finish as I have actually playing the level, and have scoured every level for any stuck soldiers and found none.

I'm on Windows 11, with decent and very modern hardware. This issue has occasionally happened to me on my Xbox 360 copy, but never for more than 30s or so.

Does anyone know if this is a common occurence, and if there's any sort of fix? I found a paragraph on the TS wiki saying that artillery can cause soldiers to land and get stuck spinning due to a bug, but I haven't seen any stuck/spinning soldiers, and this has happened to me in a playthrough of the first level with purely machine guns (I mean I guess a barrel explosion could've still caused it?).